# Glitchy Z-order in Mesh

Tags: mesh, 3d-view

My mesh seems to have a problem with Z-order, unrelated to doubles or X-ray.
I've tried exporting this to obj, tossing it through Noesis, I've been unable to get rid of this issue. Is the mesh just bugged or have I missed a crucial setting somewhere? Effects viewport and cripples render.

[image]

From Blender version 2.79.7, but this seems to occur in every versions (2.8 / 2.79).

[.blend DL](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/291675838309597185/638108185500057627/GlitchyZ.blend)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Perspective Transform is having trouble with the minimum Z-clip being set to 0. Go to the <kbd>N</kbd> Properties Region of the 3D view > 'View' panel, and set the 'Start' and 'End' of the clip to sensible values for your project, avoiding a Start of 0.

If you want the **TL;DR**, check out the 'Remapping the Z coordinate' paragraph on [this page](https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/3d-basic-rendering/perspective-and-orthographic-projection-matrix/building-basic-perspective-projection-matrix). Note that, if n=0, then f*n is always 0, and information is lost.

Comment: 0 is actually 0.000001 though? Guess that's a tad too small. Thanks!

Comment: @InTheBeef sure.. I thought of mentioning that.. (f * nearly 0) is small enough to wipe out a lot of  the floating points in the range you want to resolve.